# Joining two tables with a sum( ) table

Tags: sql, database

I currently have a query that shows the people in my team, and their current role (which is looked up from another table):

```
SELECT firstName + ' ' + lastName as Name,
       RTS_ROLE.roleDescription as `Current Role`, 
FROM RTS_STAFF, RTS_ROLE
WHERE RTS_STAFF.staffRole = RTS_ROLE.roleID 
AND staffDeleted <> true
ORDER BY roleID;
```

And another query that lists the weekly hours worked by each person:

```
SELECT RTS_STAFF.staffId, Sum(IIf(Isnull(Monday),0,Monday)
+IIf(Isnull(Tuesday),0,Tuesday)
+IIf(Isnull(Wednesday),0,Wednesday)
+IIf(Isnull(Thursday),0,Thursday)
+IIf(Isnull(Friday),0,Friday)) AS `Weekly Hours`
FROM WORKING_HOURS, RTS_STAFF
WHERE RTS_STAFF.staffId = WORKING_HOURS.staffID 
AND Date() > WORKING_HOURS.EffectiveFrom 
GROUP BY RTS_STAFF.staffId;
```

I've tried (unsuccessfully) to join these queries by placing the second query as a subquery in the first with no avail: I'm getting 'You have written a subquery that can return more than one field without using the EXIST keyword in the main query..."

I'm trying to get a query that will display the staff name, role name and 'current' total working hours from the same query. Can someone give me a clue how this could be achieved, or  what I'm doing wrong (no doubt something embarrassingly simple).

Happy to provide more information if it will help.

```
Table structure:
RTS_ROLE: (lookup table)
(pk)RoleID: number
roleDescription: string

RTS_STAFF
(pk)staffId: number
firstName: string
lastName: string
staffRole: number (fk to RTS_ROLE.roleID)
staffDeleted: boolean

WORKING_HOURS:
(pk)workingWeekID: number
staffID: number (fk to RTS_STAFF.staffId)
Monday: number
Tuesday: number
...
Friday:number
EffectiveFrom: date
```

We're using (don't laugh) MS Access 2007

Comment: Can You post table structures (only important columns) and SQL database engine name and version ? (i will recreate this tables and will try to provide an answer)

Comment: I've added the table structure to the original post; thanks for your efforts!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have access to MsAccess but I prepared something in MySQL (your IIF is similar to MySQL's IF):

```
SELECT staff.staffid,
       staff.firstname + ' ' + staff.lastname AS Name,
       role.roledescription                   AS `Current Role`,
       Sum(IF(Isnull(monday), 0, monday)
           + IF(Isnull(tuesday), 0, tuesday)
           + IF(Isnull(wednesday), 0, wednesday)
           + IF(Isnull(thursday), 0, thursday)
           + IF(Isnull(friday), 0, friday))   AS `Weekly Hours`
FROM   working_hours,
       rts_staff staff,
       rts_role role
WHERE  staff.staffrole = role.roleid
       AND staff.staffdeleted <> true
       AND staff.staffid = working_hours.staffid
       AND Now() > working_hours.effectivefrom
GROUP  BY staff.staffid,
          staff.firstname + ' ' + staff.lastname,
          role.roledescription
```

based on this structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `rts_staff` (
  `staffid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `staffrole` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `firstname` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lastname` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `staffdeleted` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`staffid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB


CREATE TABLE `rts_role` (
  `roleid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `roledescription` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`roleid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB


CREATE TABLE `working_hours` (
  `staffid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `effectivefrom` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `monday` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tuesday` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `wednesday` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `thursday` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `friday` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`staffid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

Comment: `NOW()`  function can be changed for date what You desire :)

Comment: Thanks so much for your help, I was (admittedly through ignorance) bashing my head against the wall for hours over that!

Answer (score 1):

try something like this:

```
SELECT firstName + ' ' + lastName as Name,
   RTS_ROLE.roleDescription as `Current Role`, x.weeklyhours
   FROM RTS_STAFF s INNER JOIN
   RTS_ROLE r ON s.staffRole = r.roleID INNER JOIN
   (
     SELECT RTS_STAFF.staffId, Sum(IIf(Isnull(Monday),0,Monday)
     +IIf(Isnull(Tuesday),0,Tuesday)
     +IIf(Isnull(Wednesday),0,Wednesday)
     +IIf(Isnull(Thursday),0,Thursday)
     +IIf(Isnull(Friday),0,Friday)) AS weeklyhours
     FROM WORKING_HOURS, RTS_STAFF
     WHERE RTS_STAFF.staffId = WORKING_HOURS.staffID 
     AND Date() > WORKING_HOURS.EffectiveFrom 
     GROUP BY RTS_STAFF.staffId
   ) x ON x.staffID = s.staffID
WHERE  s.staffDeleted <> true
ORDER BY r.roleID;
```